# Is it possible to animate flexbox elements on scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-transitions

Is it possible to animate flex elements up on scroll?

I'm trying to achieve this: https://codepen.io/Sergiop79/pen/bxjGEe

with the elements below (styled in flexbox), either the whole "row" or individual "col".

I haven't been able to find anything regarding this for Flexbox so I'd just like to know if it's even possible. Thank you!

```
<about id="about" class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="about1">
          <img src="1-AB.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="about1a">
          <h3>About</h3>
          <p>Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="about2">
          <img src="2-AB.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="about2a">
            <h3>Aboot</h3>
            <p>Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="about3">
          <img src="3-AB.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="about3a">
            <h3>Abute</h3>
            <p>Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </about>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set their `opacity` to `0` and `transform:transationY(100%)` and make a class called `show` or something with properties of `opacity:1;` and `transform:translateY(0);`

then you will need this *JS* code

```js
    var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
    document.addEventListener("scroll",function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++){
           if(columns[i].getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight){
              columns[i].classList.add("show");
           }
        }
    });
```

```css
.col{
width:100%;
height:300px;
background:#555;
border:1px solid #000;
margin-bottom:50px;
opacity:0;
transform:translateY(100%);
transition:opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}

.show{
opacity:1;
transform:translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
<div class="col"></div>
```

where `columns[i].getBoundingClientRect().top < window.innerHeight` checks if the `div` in shown in the window at the scrolling time or not